# What is the difference between a derivative and a differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If function $y=x^2$, then the derivative of $y$ is $2x$. We write the derivative as either $f'(x)=2x$ or $\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}=2x$.

In this case $\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}=2x$ is also a differential equation.

But if we have the function $y=ax^2+bx+c$

then in this case we will have $\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}= 2ax+b$.

Is $\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}= 2ax+b$ also considered as a differential equation or we will have to remove all arbitrary constants from the function to call it a differential equation?

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to learn about the use of mathjax and improve your writing in this site.

Answer (score 4):

You can view the derivative operator $D(f)=f'=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f$ as a function which produces a new function, it's derivative. So the derivative of a function is a new function which gives some information about the old function.

A differential equation is an equation with a function and its derivatives. Where you try to solve for the unknown function.

A first order linear differential equation looks like:
$$f'(x)+a(x)f(x)=R(x)$$
So the examples you gave were differential equations with $a(x)=0$.
But differential equations can be much more complicated then a derivative. A simple example is:
$$f'(x)=f(x)$$ 
With a solution $e^x$.
Second order linear differential equations look like:
$$f''(x)+a(x)f'(x)+f(x)=R(x)$$
But even a monster like:
$$f'''(x)\cdot \sin(f(x))=e^x$$ 
Is a differential equation.

Comment: A few typos: you've got *it's* instead of *its* and *where* instead of *were*. (I can't see any others.)

Comment: @timtfj are you sure it should be were? Because internet tells me "Were is a state of being verb used to describe something that happened in the past.".

Comment: Well, either "the examples are differential equations" or "the examples were differential equations". "Where" is a conjunction introducing a subordinate clause, so "the examples where the differential equations have $a(x)=0$ do such-and-such" would make sense, but as it stands "where"
doesn't make a sentence.  (English is my native language.)

Comment: I have read that differential equation is an equation that involves an unknown variable and its derivative but there are some cases in which the derivative or derivatives are present in an equation while the function itself is not present, but yet the equation is regarded as a differential equation of the function. Why is so ?

Comment: For example in my book the differential equation for the function "y=ax^2+bx+c" is

d^3 y/dx^3=0
This equation contains the third order derivative of the variable "y" but the variable "y" itself is absent in this equation but yet the equation is considered as a differential equation according to the book which sounds against the definition i have read. @fejfo

Comment: @Alex In my book "a differential equation is an equation with an unknown function as it's first or higher derivative" is used as the definition. So the function it's self doesn't need to appear at all. But if you call that a differential equation or not is really just a semantic.